# Running application on a locked down Win10 machine

Tags: c#, windows-10, launching-application

I've got a small program I made to improve on simple work efficiencies. In effect it's just an application that has direct links to applications and websites, allows text input and formats it appropriately so this information to be stored and recalled quickly.

This has been running for years on our corporate machines (running Windows 7 and 8) just by emailing the .exe to myself with a password protected zip and starting it on the machine, but we're now upgrading to Windows 10 machines and these are locked down to the point where no foreign software can be ran. I know the reasons for this are security, but I am looking for a way around it or alternative way of deploying the software.

I am looking into getting the software authorised for use, but in effect this will be unlikely given how often I update and change things on it (or business changes frequently in terms of process and operation) - it would just be inconvenient.

It's a C# program. NET 4.5.

I can't get admin permission on these machines. Is there anything I can do?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you can consider using `ClickOnce`, or the new `MSIX`, or Publish the app on the `Microsoft Store` ? I agree there is more difficulty to do this, mostly due to security reasons and also attempt to promote the Store.

Answer (score -1):

If you cannot run untrusted applications, then instead build your solution within another product that you can use.

For example-- you can probably do all of your direct links to websites and any text input / reformatting you might need with javascript entirely within an html page.  Open the .html file with your browser and there you have it.

You can also do many things with VBA scripts in Excel or Word documents.

You may also be able to use powershell to do your automation.

Comment: IMHO we should not be helping users to circumvent security imposed by their company.

Comment: My answer does not circumvent security.  The security policy does not allow unrecognized applications to be executed.  It does not necessarily prohibit automating things like navigating to documents.  I simply offered a programmatic solution to simple automation tasks on a system that does not allow you to install a new executable application.  Does this merit a downvote?